# Custom many-to-many mapping with CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Start using CodeFirst in my MVC projects and have some trouble.
I have in-use database with some predefined schema.
There are some tables:

```
[Persons]
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Birthday] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Zip] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Tax] [money] NOT NULL,
[Memo] [varbinary](max) NULL

[Seminars]
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
```

and many-to-many connected table

```
[QualRef]
[SemID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RefID] [bigint] NOT NULL
```

where SemID referenced to Seminars.ID and RefID referenced to Persons.ID

I'm trying to fix-up my CodeFirst schema binding using configuration class:

```
class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        internal PersonConfiguration()
        {
            this.HasMany(i => i.Seminars)
                .WithMany(c => c.Persons)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapLeftKey("SemID");
                    mc.MapRightKey("RefID");
                    mc.ToTable("QualRef");
                });
        }
    }
```

and register it with this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Persons");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
    }
```

But when I run app using this models error occured - CodeFirst trying to find some table "dbo.People" (?!) and it does not exist (expected). Thank for good answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the code like this,

```
class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Persons");

            this.HasMany(i => i.Seminars)
                .WithMany(c => c.Persons)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapLeftKey("SemID");
                    mc.MapRightKey("RefID");
                    mc.ToTable("QualRef");
                });
        }
    }
```

//...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: problem is that ToTable("Persons") don't have any reason. Problem is with table "QualRef"

Comment: Did you tried my code? Try changing the order of code in `OnModelCreating` in your code to call base method at the end after  `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());` .

Comment: Yes, Jayantha, i tried this. Problem is that (as i think) EF trying to create (or associate) new mapping for connecting table. Why it do this - I don't know.

Comment: Tnx you very much! Coz first time I remove ToTable() (think that problem is with QualRef) solution works wrong. After this I generate DB creation script and check that problem is with Persons. Code works good now!